# Can we take a shower with salty water

Tags: water, salt, bath

I just move to area near to beach. Unfortunately we have a problem to access fresh water. So, I decide to dig a well about 8meters deep, but the water is salty. I then install carbon filter and softener. The taste become better (less salty) but still have a little bit of salty taste. Other then salty taste everything is okay (color is clear, no odor, nothing) just like a good clean water.

Is that okay if we take a shower with this water?

Comment: please add your research about this, and tell the community why it isn't satisfied you

Comment: Do you plan to cook with it as well? Wash your food with it before cooking? People do a lot of things with water.

Answer (score 2):

Humans have been spending hours per day immersed in sea water without harm since before recorded history. Many sportsmen, professional divers, and fishermen still do. Other than the mild drying effects salt water has on the skin, I can find no documentation of harm from exposure to it.

What else might be in the water can only be revealed by laboratory testing. If you want to be sure the water is free of harmful contaminants, you'll need to have it tested. Never a bad idea with well water.

Comment: And yet (at least according to [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy_shower)), people aboard naval ships use scarce fresh water to shower. Seems odd.

Comment: @msh210 I don't know how true that still is since modern ships distill their own fresh water from sea water. Cruise ships, for example, provide virtually unlimited fresh water to a couple thousand passengers who don't bother trying to limit their use.

Comment: Hmm I agree with @msh210 on this one. I'm thinking about looking into this question to see if I can find some documentation of harmful exposure.

Comment: @DaveL By all means add another answer but sailors use fresh water to shower with for the simple reason that showering with seawater is unpleasant because it leaves dried salt on your skin. Anyone who's been in the ocean and then dried off without a fresh water rinse knows this.